# OpenCV pre-req install error python

Tags: opencv, installation, homebrew, python-3.5

I am trying to install OpenCV for python but what I need to do first is install some prerequisites using homebrew and it has all gone fine until I type in the command:

```
brew install eigen tbb
```

And thus the error displays:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step 
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
```

I have looked at other solutions on SO but I am hesitant to try it in fear that I might lose documents/change directories/etc. If anyone has had a similar problem or can help me, PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Install each package independently : `brew install eigen` then `brew install tbb` in order to determine which one is causing the error.

Comment: Both of these packages install without problems on my machine. Did you do a `brew update` before?

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`?